# One thread unable to change another thread's variable even on making the variable volatile

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, caching, volatile

I have the following `Processor` class:

```
public class Processor extends Thread {

    private volatile boolean running = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                System.out.println("Hello " + i);
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void shutdown() {
        running = false;
    }
}
```

Following is from my `main` method:

```
Processor processor = new Processor();
processor.start();

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.nextLine();

processor.shutdown();
```

In my `Processor` class I have the `volatile boolean` variable `running`, which I have set to `true`. A loop inside my `run` method is running as long as `running` is `true`. I have a separate method `shutdown`, which when executed sets the value of `running` to `false` and hence stops the loop inside `run` method.

From my `main` method I am running the loop in a separate thread, and then executing the `shutdown` method from main thread.

Despite setting variable `running` as `volatile`, I am unable to stop the loop execution.

Where am I going wrong?

I'm using IntelliJ IDE.

Comment: Try to remove reading anything from the console (e.g. replace it with some `sleep`)

Comment: @DenisZavedeev Even on placing a `sleep` in not reading from console same result

Comment: Oh, I was thinking that it was possible for input to be ignored. The answer by ControlAltDel should help

Comment: That will help for this specific problem, in general my aim is to utilize the `volatile` `keyword`

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit more? What do you want to utilize `volatile` _for_? What do you expect to happen? What happens after you apply the provided answer?

Comment: @DenisZavedeev `volatile` keyword is used to ensure that a thread does not cache a variable and another thread is able to change it. Then why am I not able to change running to `false` from a separate `main` thread.

Comment: @DenisZavedeev this program is insignifant, here I am trying to learn use of `volatile` keyword

Comment: Add this inside the `for` loop: `if (!running) break;`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn it magically works, but why does it work?

Comment: Use thread interrupts to stop the thread from further execution , put the interrupted check after the while(true) and break if interrupted , also use atomic reference if you still what use a variable based check , but if still want to use volatile then put a synchronised keyword on shutdown method, to ensure a hard write to ram.

Comment: Outer check (`while (running)`) is only checked after the inner for has done it's job - so every ~100 seconds.

Comment: Replace `for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)` with `for (int i = 0; i < 1000 && running; i++)` and remove the `while (running)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap the while and for loops. This way you can short-circuit the running

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    while (running) {
            System.out.println("Hello " + i);
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }
```

I've let if to you to fix the indentation :)

Comment: Okay,  but my main aim here is to use the `volatile` `keyword`. Why is it not working?

Comment: Here, this program is insignificant, I am learning the use of volatile keyword, and my main query is - even after using volatile, the second thread is not letting main thread to change the variable value?

Comment: *"Why is it not working?"* - It is a simple *logic problem* in your code.  The code as you wrote it only tests the flag once every 100 seconds.

Comment: @PayelSenapati Actually, the problem *is* significant, because in the original code that you wrote, once the first *running* check is cleared, it *never checks it again and there is no way to short-circuit / stop it